# Find first and last order date for ID (same id might appear multiple times) in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of orders with the following columuns: Buyer ID, Order Date, Order Value

I need to add one column that lists the FIRST order date, and one that lists the LAST order date. In case of only 1 order, the date would be the same in both columns.

**EG - this is what I have**

```
Buyer ID   Order Date
1          1/31/2016
2          2/27/2016   
1          5/31/2016
```

**This is what I would like**

```
Buyer ID   Order Date   Last Order   First Order
1          1/31/2016    5/31/2016    1/31/2016
2          2/27/2016    2/27/2016    2/27/2016
1          5/31/2016    5/31/2016    1/31/2016
```

I have over 1000 buyer IDs, not all of them have multiple orders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume your "Buyer ID" values are in cells `A2:A4`, and your "Order Date" values are in cells `B2:B4`.  To get the "Last" value in cell `C2` (the topmost non-header cell in your "Last Order" column), type or paste the following formula, then press <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Enter</kbd> to enter it:

```
=MAX(IF($A$2:$A$4 = A2, $B$2:$B$4))
```

Then, to get the "First" value in cell `D2` (the topmost non-header cell in your "First Order" column), type or paste the following formula, and again press <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Enter</kbd> to enter it:

```
=MIN(IF($A$2:$A$4 = A2, $B$2:$B$4))
```

Then, simply formula-copy the cells `C2:D2` down to as many rows as you have data.

Please note that it is important to enter the formulas using <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Enter</kbd> instead of just pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, as this will create an array formula. Otherwise, in each cell you would get the `MAX` or `MIN` values for the entire range `A2:A4`, without taking the "Buyer ID" criterion into consideration.

Comment: I only have one issue, the file now takes a very long time to open/save/edit.. Any way to make excel faster with Array Formulas?

Comment: Not that I know of. How many rows do you have exactly, and how long is the delay?

Comment: almost 3k rows, but will gradually increase every month.. The delay is probably around 5min.. with 100% cpu usage.. (i5 3570k overclocked at 4.5ghz)

Comment: I've never needed to use an array formula on a range that large, so I didn't realize the delay would be so bad. If you can save all the rows for the `Buyer ID` and `Order Date` columns as a CSV file, then upload the file (or just its text) somewhere and post a link to it, I can take a look. However, it might take me a while. The machine on which I run Excel suffered a rather bad HDD crash this morning, and I may need a few days to recover from it.

Comment: Thank you for your help MJH, however the Buyer IDs are actual customers names so I will need to ask my boss if I can discolse this info (I dont want to be in trouble :P). I will let you know! Thanks!